# Passwords From Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, password-recovery, firefox-profile

I have all my data in directory, have access to `logins.json` and the rest of the files from previous linux installation. I'm still on linux. Basic question, how to get to firefox passwords?
I can't use virtual machine with windows - computer is too old.

Comment: Can you just run firefox using the old profile folder (or a copy of)?

Comment: If it can be done on linux, yes.

Comment: Firefox runs the same way across platforms/OSes and the user profiles are the same but in a different folder or, better, the same folder name in a different location.